# Container Image not see in GitLab registry

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, docker-registry

I am trying to push a Docker Compose file to GitLab Container Registry. The commands are getting executed successfully, however, I do not see the image in the registry. When I tried to push the Dockerfile, that works. The Compose file isn't. No known solutions for this. Is searched for similar posts but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker executor with Docker-in-Docker service `docker-compose` command is not available by default and it has to be installed. You can see here if you might be hitting some more limitations in your CI/CD configuration [using docker build](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-the-docker-image-docker-in-docker)